# Difference between strictly increasing and increasing functions

Tags: derivatives

What is the precise difference between strictly increasing and increasing functions??
I see these terms being thrown around a lot
My guess is that strictly increasing mean that derivative is **only greater than 0** and in case of just increasing derivative can be **greater than or equal** or 0?

Comment: Something not noted in the answers is that, even in the differentiable case, it is not the case that a function is strictly increasing iff its derivative is positive everywhere. Indeed, the function $f(x)=x^3$ is strictly increasing, but $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: The definitions also imply that $f(x) = 0$ is both a (non-strictly) increasing and decreasing flat-line function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your inituition about derivatives is only $3$ quarters correct: If the function $f$ under consideration is differentiable in the considered interval open $I$, then

$$ f \text{ is increasing in } I  \Longleftrightarrow f'(x) \ge 0\; \forall x \in I.$$

OTOH, under the same conditions only one  of the implications holds for strictly increasing functions:

$$ f \text{ is strictly increasing in } I  \Longleftarrow f'(x) > 0\; \forall x \in I.$$

The other implication is wrong, for example $f(x)=x^3$ is strictly increasing in $I=(-1,1)$, while the derivative is zero at $x=0$.

Answer (score 10):

You're basically correct (update: as stated in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3333511) and question comment by [Wojowu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/127263/wojowu), I forgot to add that strictly increasing differentiable functions do not require the derivative to always be positive), except the concept of "strictly increasing" and "increasing" functions also applies to non-differentiable functions. In particular, for all $x \gt y$, where $x$ and $y$ are in the function domain, *strictly increasing* means $f(x) \gt f(y)$ while just *increasing* means $f(x) \ge f(y)$.

Comment: To give a specific example, a constant function is increasing but not strictly increasing.

Answer (score 8):

Strictly increasing means that $f(x)> f(y)$ for $x>y$.
While increasing means that $f(x)\geq f(y)$ for $x>y$.

Example:

$f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x$ is strictly increasing.

And the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto \lfloor x\rfloor$ is increasing.

$\lfloor x\rfloor$ notes the flooring-function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Definition_and_properties

And looks like this:

[image]

Note that this function stays constant on certain intervals, but increases over time.